# CSS hover using Javascript DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

i'm having a hard time finding a solution to this problem: I'm trying to make certain CSS elements like `border-color` or `a` change different colors on on mouseover. I'm using DOM to escape iframe limits and change code outside of the bounds. Here's my code so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.parent.document.getElementById("screenshots").style.backgroundImage="url(bg.png)";
window.parent.document.getElementById("screenshots").style.color="#000";    
window.parent.document.getElementById("description_container").style.marginBottom="-4px";

$(window.parent.document.getElementById("screenshots")).children("a").each(function (i, o) {         
    $(o).children("img").each(function (i, img) {
        $(img).css({
        /*  "border": "5px", */
            "border-color": "rgba(119, 94, 4, .75)",
            "border-style": "solid",
            "border-radius": "10px",
            "opacity": "0.9",
        });
    });
});
```

For example where it says `"border-color": "rgba(119, 94, 4, .75)",` I would like it to change the color on hover.

Thanks!

Comment: use `.hover(function(){}, function(){})` in jQuery, for JavaScript, use `onmouseover()`

Comment: Thank you for you quick response! I'm confused on how I would implement that into my code though. Can you explain further on how I could use jQuery in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a big fan of relying on javascript for this. You could add a stylesheet to the target document at runtime with all the rules you wish to implement:

```
$(window.parent.document.head).append('<style type="text/css">a:hover{color:red !important;}</style>');
```

### Update:

<del>I'm struggling to reproduce this on jsfiddle due to cross-domain limitations.</del> [Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ovfiddle/3tNnE/10/) is not affected by the crossdomain limitation by including [another fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ovfiddle/3tNnE/9/) into its own iframe.

Comment: Thanks for replying. This javascript code is inside of a HTML document itself. Would I still be able to use that code inside the <head> tag with my current code? Also, how would using document.head help?

Comment: @Sosa: yes, that's not an issue; if you're using jQuery remember to add the code to only fire on domready though. The final selector above is cheaper to look up, but I'm certain the original one would have worked just as well.

Comment: It worked thanks so much! This is the line I added `$(window.parent.document.head).append('<style type="text/css">img:hover{border-color:#D81717 !important;}</style>');`.

Answer (score 0):

Like Eric Yin has mentioned:

you can bind a mouseover event to a a specific element or declare it with your element in the html.
In this same loop for every element you loop over bind a onmouseover event to each a element. This syntax is rather confusing, or I'm just not as used to jQuery. Mind I say I hope you are doing this as an exercise because setting styles in js is not a good way to approach this. It would be something like this?

```
$(img).onmouseover = function() { 
    this.css( {
        "border-color": "rgba(119, 94, 4, .75)"
    });
};
```

jQuery .hover is probably a better choice since you can bind 2 functions to toggle between. With this you would probably need to also bind a onmouseout to reset the border.

Honestly using css :hover class is the best and most efficient solution.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: Edited the fiddle (and the code below). Class defines if the element is to changed or not.

Here's [a fiddle for jQuery solution](http://jsfiddle.net/kjQEj/6/) almost straight out from [the jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/css/).

The code:

```
$(".change").hover(function () {
  $(this).css({
    "border-color": "rgba(88, 44, 4, .75)",
    "border-radius": "10px",
    "opacity": "0.5"});
  }, function () {
var cssObj = {
    "border": "5px",
    "border-color": "rgba(119, 94, 4, .75)",
    "border-style": "solid",
    "border-radius": "10px",
    "opacity": "0.9"
}
  $(this).css(cssObj);
});
```

​​